# Use Destructor Equivalant to find a function is processed

Tags: c#, static, destructor

I am using one of the classes written by John Skeet and modified it in a project.

Some Code..

```
public sealed class DataProvider
{
    private static readonly DataProvider instance = new DataProvider();

    static DataProvider() { }
    private DataProvider() { }

    public static DateTime InstanceStartDate;

    public static DataProvider Instance
    {
        get
        {
            InstanceStartDate = DateTime.UTCNow;
            // Set a Function Call Start Time..
            return instance;
        }
    }

    // Hundresds of functions will reside here....
    public void FunctionNo150()
    {
       // Database call which can take say 5-10 seconds..
       LongProcess();

       // DONT WANT TO SET FUNCTION COMPLETE HERE BUT AT SAY SOME DESTRUCTOR
    }
```

This will have lots of function in it which are calling another Dlls.

I can call the function like:

```
DataProvider.Instance.Function150();
```

I will have a timer which will run say after every 1 second and i need to detect if the function is taking too much time.

Now i can detect when a function is started by setting a static datetime variable.

**BUT HOW can i find out the function is completed.
Can i have some destructor or so?? where i will set the static variable function complete time rather than writing in every functions.**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Note that "the time you obtained the instance" isn't necessarily "the time the method started". *Why* don't you want to record the time within the method itself?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to create a timer in different thread that will keep on checking the time a particulat function is taking if the difference is over say 5 seconds will show a loading message to the user.

Comment: so the really problem is that you not want to add such many similar codes to the 'Hundresds of functions'?

Comment: I don't think using a mutable singleton is a good approach then - apart from anything else, what would you expect to happen if two threads called methods at the same time? I suggest you re-evaluate your design choices - consider using a delegate to represent "this is what I want to call" and wrap that in a timer...

Comment: @JiangYD Exactly. Just my timer will check say two variables every 1 second say and show a message

Comment: @JonSkeet The timer will just check the variables say Function Start Date and Current date and will show a message. I dont want to access functions at all. Just to show users if some function got stuck

Comment: Well, this looks like a bad design to me, I'm afraid. I would start a separate timer for each function you start. When the timer fires, see whether the function has completed - and if it hasn't, alert the user. Simple and avoids global state.

Comment: i agree with @JonSkeet. but you can try some cool things like reflect, wrapping all functions within one function call and do timer one place.

Comment: @JonSkeet That sounds good. But how to send the timer which is created in this dll send the data back to UI project or trigger the UI project

Comment: @JiangYD How to wrap all gunction winthin one function call. I have over 500+ function which are still growing. Any code sample is appreciated

Comment: you're doing wrong, you need change the 500+ function calls to one like:`execute(string cmd, object[] params){/*set new timer here*/switch(cmd){case:"No150":LongProcess(); case:"xxx":xxx();}/*cancel timer here*/}`

Comment: @JiangYD That actually seems scary with lot of functions and you constantly writing functions on daily basis but even thanks for code, cheers